How would I go about supplying the measurement circuit with multiple batteries ouputting microAmps of current
If I am doing a test for lithium-ion batteries where I am trying to measure a small current when I apply a small load (on the order of microAmps)
How would I go about using this same current to power the measuring circuit? The expected total current output should be in the microAmps.  I have selected the measurement ICs with a supply voltage of 3.3 V and 2.7 V. How would I go about creating the supply?
My first thought was to use an inductor to store the energy as there will be a constant current output.

the leakage current of a battery is an internal current, not something external that you can directly measure or use to power anything? Ignoring the "powering the measurement circuit" aspect of it, how are you planning to measure the leakage current, at all?

@MarcusMüller By applying some very small load. So my thought is that the leakage current or some very small microamp current is outputted and over multiple cells can be added up to some usable current.

that's not what leakage current in a battery is, rel; it's not a current through an external load.


How would I go about using this same current to power the measuring
circuit?

Use a low side current sense resistor for the return current pathway. The problem is you need to measure both the test and the circuit that you are measuring. If the test circuit has a constant current, you could measure the current of the test circuit and then turn on the circuit of the current you want to measure.
A better thing would be to use two batteries in a circuit like this, then you don't have to worry about it:

https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa336/sboa336.pdf?ts=1718234864190
